# prettify-symbols-mode character replacement regex

Tags: python, prettify-symbols-mode

I'm using the new emacs 24.4 `prettify-symbols-mode`, but it isn't behaving consistently.

I turn it on with:

```
(prettify-symbols-mode t)
(global-prettify-symbols-mode t)
```

And I'm trying to change the way python source code looks with the
follownig setup:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (push '("**2" . ?²) prettify-symbols-alist)
            (push '("_x" . ?ᵪ) prettify-symbols-alist)
            (push '("sum" . ?∑) prettify-symbols-alist)))
```

This works, but not consistently. For example,

`x**2 x_x and sum(x)` all look good.

The inconsistent part is that x**23 maintains the superscript 2, but
the 3 is regular. But if I say `x**2+2`, or `x**2,` then the `**2` is not pretty (and it should be). I'd like the 2 to only be superscript when it is
followed by certain characters (space, plus, comma, etc.).
Alternatively, not superscript if followed by [0-9].

Meanwhile, sum behaves correctly. `sum(`, `sum**2`, `sum+`, and others are
pretty (as they should be) and `summer` is not (correctly).

Comment: The documentation for prettify-symbols-alist says: *Each element looks like (SYMBOL . CHARACTER), where the symbol matching SYMBOL (a string, not a regexp) will be shown as CHARACTER instead.*, so you won't be able to use regular expressions.

Comment: Please use `M-x report-emacs-bug` to report this problem, which will probably require extending prettify-symbols-mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation for `prettify-symbols-alist`, you cannot use regular expressions here:

> Each element looks like (SYMBOL . CHARACTER), where the symbol matching SYMBOL **(a string, not a regexp)** will be shown as CHARACTER instead.

`pretty-symbols-mode` uses `regexp-opt` internally, which creates a big regular expression from all the strings in the car position of each of the alist pairs.  If you really want regular expressions, you are probably better off defining font-lock keywords yourself, outside of the confines of `prettify-symbols-mode`.

Answer (score 5):

The closest I have gotten to replicating this is to customize the way emacs sets the font for characters for each mode I want to change

```
(add-to-list 'font-lock-extra-managed-props 'display)

(font-lock-add-keywords 'latex-mode ;; you can change the mode here
                        '(("\\(wordone\\).*?wordtwo" 1 '(face nil display "∑"))))
```

This will replace `wordone` with `∑` as long as it is on the same line as `wordtwo`
when font-lock-mode is enabled in latex-mode

The 1 refers to regexp group one in the string denoted by `\\( \\)`

Comment: Although this does work, adding this to my configuration (using Doom Emacs) breaks `image-mode` for me -- images will not display. Just a warning for anyone stumbling across this.

Answer (score 0):

@rekado is right.

> Each element looks like (SYMBOL . CHARACTER), where the symbol
>   matching SYMBOL (a string, not a regexp) will be shown as CHARACTER
>   instead.

but there is more

> CHARACTER can be a character, or it can be a list or vector, in
>   which case it will be used to compose the new symbol as per the
>   third argument of ‘compose-region’.

So it can let you do some cool stuffs like y superscript star index i

```
(setq prettify-symbols-alist
      '(("yy" . (?y (tr . Bc) 1645 (br . cr) ?i))))
```

see the `C-h compose-region`. I'm not going to lie it took me a long time to figure out how to do it and I still have many questions but my understanding of the doc says that the N, are the characters. 0, 2, 4, and the N+1 are the composition rules. But these composition rules seems to be reversed. For example 'Bc' is for 'y' and 'tr' is for '1645'.