# Prettify string, find by regex

Tags: regular-expressions, font-lock

I want to replace the regular expression `` `.*` `` by bolding `.*` and not displaying the backticks. So I want `` `elem` `` to become **elem**

I looked into these questions about how to prettify strings rather than chars:

[Using Prettify Symbols with strings instead of characters](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34808/using-prettify-symbols-with-strings-instead-of-characters)

[prettify-symbols-mode and multi-character replacements?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36572/prettify-symbols-mode-and-multi-character-replacements)

I do not understand the answers however. But the answer to [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3753/prettify-symbols-mode-character-replacement-regex) question states prettify-symbols does not support regular expressions anyway and that one needs to use font lock keywords. The [wiki entry](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FontLockKeywords) is not exactly helpful in my opinion; it does not show what the code on the page actually does, but as far as I understand it, apparently it coincidentally is supposed to make some keywords bold (page uses the word *highlight*... whatever that is supposed to mean here). So I copied and modified it into my init.el like so:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'haskell-mode
                    '(("`.*`"
                       (1 'font-lock-variable-name-face)
                       (3 'font-lock-keyword-face)
                       (5 'font-lock-keyword-face)
                       (6 'font-lock-keyword-face))))
```

When I do <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> `font-lock-mode` a string matched by the regex won't by changed.

But I did not expect this to work as I have no idea what I am doing here anyway. Am I even going in the right direction here with that font-lock thing?

Comment: See the Elisp manual about `font-lock-keywords` - node [Search-based Fontification](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html). Read it carefully.

Comment: Sounds like that does not do what I want.